# Make animation run only once in bge

Tags: game-engine

i want to make a animation play one time and don't play again.
How i do that?

I'm using logic bricks.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? Why are you using a message to trigger the animation? What is the purpose of the action? Can you please explain your game scene?

Answer (score 0):

Let the message set a property to value 1. Then add a property sensor: If property = 1 --> play action.

OR

Let the message set the state with the "State" actuator. In the another state, play the action triggered by an always sensor.

It will never play again ;)

I see you wrote "Vanish". If you want that the object disappears, use the "Invisibility"-Actuator instead of an action actuator and turn "Visible" off.